# pkill does not seem to remove dpkg process in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: installation, gitlab, ubuntu-18.04, dpkg, pkill

I'm currently using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and I am trying to install GitLab via the instructions on https://www.linode.com/docs/development/version-control/install-gitlab-with-docker/.

Initially, I was following the instructions to download and install GitLab via Ubuntu 18.04 LTS at: https://about.gitlab.com/install/#ubuntu, which lead to a problem similar to the problem posed here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/637962/gitlab-install-is-stuck-at-0-on-ubuntu.

I then tried removing the processes involving `dpkg` with the help of `sudo pkill gitlab`, following the instructions posed at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94430/process-id-and-killing-process-ps-commmand.

However, I obtained the following error:

[image]

Is there a way to resolve this such that *you must manually run `sudo dpkg --configure -`' to correct the problem* does not appear again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question, running `dpkg --configure -a` once should resolve the issue and you won't see the message again on future `apt install` execution. This problem arises because you kill `apt` in the middle of it doing work.

It seems like the root of the issue may be that you cannot access the GitLab package repository, or CloudFront, to pull the package?

- Are you able to access https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ee from this system? i.e. `curl https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ee`
- If the above works, can you try downloading an actual package manually to see if that works? i.e. `wget --content-disposition https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ee/packages/ubuntu/xenial/gitlab-ee_12.2.4-ee.0_amd64.deb/download.deb`

The image itself is served via CloudFront. So I wonder if you're able to connect to https://packages.gitlab.com but not cloudfront.net once the actual file is served.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input! I am able to run the above two lines without any hitches. Following which I am able to proceed with the installation and the error message has not appeared since :)